# Elasticsearch Automatic Synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking at Elasticsearch to handle search queries made by users in on my website.

Say that I have a document `person` with field `vehicles_owned` which is a list of strings. For example:

```
{
    "name":"james",
    "surname":"smith",
    "vehicles_owned":["car","bike","ship"]
}
```

I would like to query which people own a certain vehicle. I understand it's possible to configure ES so that `boat` is treated as a synonym of `ship` and if I query with `boat` I am returned the user `james` who owns a ship.

What I don't understand is whether this is done automatically, or if I have to import lists of synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to create a custom analyzer for the `vehicles_owned` field which leverages the [`synonym` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).

So you first need to define your index like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"    <-- your synonym file
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "syn": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "surname": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "vehicles_owned": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "synonym"     <-- use the synonym analyzer here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can add all the synonyms you want to handle in the `$ES_HOME/config/synonyms.txt` file using the supported [formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#_solr_synonyms), for instance:

```
boat, ship
```

Next, you can index your documents:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/1 -d '{
    "name":"james",
    "surname":"smith",
    "vehicles_owned":["car","bike","ship"]
}'
```

And finally searching for either `ship` or `boat` will get you the above document we just indexed:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?q=vehicles_owned:boat
curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?q=vehicles_owned:ship
```